# How to assign a name to a new column that follows the structure column1*column2 in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame that consists of columns like Date, Brand1Index, Brand1Volume, Brand2Index, Brand2Volume etc.
I now want to create a new data frame that stores the product of (Brand1Index,Brand1volume), (Brand2Index, Brand2Volume) --> New data frame has one column for each brand from the other data frame. I managed to calculate the product for each brand and also put them into the new dataframe. However, I want the columns of the new data frame to be named after the function I used. For instance, when Column1 of the new data frame represents Brand1Index x Brand1Volume it shall be named like that. So far, the columns are rather named like "5 x 18.8" etc. These are values of the columns... Below is a snippet from my code:

```
    df <- NULL
    j <- 1

    for(i in seq(2, 10, 2)) {

      df[j] <- data[i]*data[i+1]

      j <- j+1
    }

    df <- data.frame(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a data frame like:

```
df

#    date brand1Index brand1Volume brand2Index brand2Volume
#   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     4           1            1           3            3
# 2     5           2            2           2            2
# 3     6           3            3           1            1
```

You run your code and get:

```
df2

#   wrongName1 wrongName2
#        <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1          1          9
# 2          4          4
# 3          9          1
```

Then you can use the following solution based in the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

names <- df1 %>%
  colnames() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  filter(value != 'date') %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(+(row_number() %% 2 == 1))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(newName = str_c(value, collapse = '_x_')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(newName) %>%
  pull()
  
df2 %>% rename_with(~ names, .cols = colnames(.))

#   brand1Index_x_brand1Volume brand2Index_x_brand2Volume
#                        <dbl>                      <dbl>
# 1                          1                          9
# 2                          4                          4
# 3                          9                          1
```

Running it one line at a time you will see that the first `mutate()` creates a new variable that pairs the names that need to be put together in a single name. The paired names are then grouped and put together. These operations give us duplicates that are removed using `distinct()` and turned into a vector by means of `pull()`.

Having the right variable names in the right order in the vector ensures that we can rename `df2` correctly in the final line.

Comment: I am gonna try this one out. Looks exactly the way I want to do it. However, I myself have found an own solution that at least copies the colname of the first data frame.

Comment: Could you also explain some lines? What exactly do you do between line 5 and the end?

Comment: @user3683131: Sure. I have edited my post to provide some explanation.